# Regex: how to exclude divs with almost similar id

Tags: javascript, regex

After querying DB and displaying results I have list of divs that are almost similarly named:

```
<div id=product_[id] ... </div>
```

When user clicks one of these divs I would like to hide other ones. And here is the problem. What regex expression can handle picking up all divs with ids starting from

```
product_
```

but excluding for example product_32. Value that has to be excluded I would like to provide as a variable.

Any help appreciated.
Michal

Comment: How are you currently hiding the elements? Show the code that does that. (Chance are that you don't need regex at all to solve this problem).

Comment: <table class="table table-hover">
<thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr id="prd_readmore_39" data-prd_id="39" style="display: none;">
<tr>
<tr id="prd_readmore_40" data-prd_id="40" style="display: table-row;">
<tr>
<tr id="prd_readmore_41" data-prd_id="41" style="display: none">
</tbody>
</table>

Comment: Currently none of them is hidden.

Comment: Give them all a common class value. When one is clicked, hide **all** of them and then immediately show the click target (by its id value).

Comment: @Michal That's what I was getting to as well. You can do that with the `document.getElementsByClassName()` and `document.getElementById()` DOM API functions. Just create a CSS class `.hidden { display: none; }` and add or remove `hidden` from the elements' classes as desired. (Side note 1: Of course you can also do it with jQuery. I'd suggest you first try it without. Side note 2: When you think about it, you don't really need element IDs at all.)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div (?=.*\bid=product_(?!32)).*?<\/div>
```

you can try like this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vD5iH9/23